# Make a grammar unambiguous?

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, context-free-grammar, ambiguity, context-free-language

I have the following problem. This grammar is ambiguous:

> stmt -> if expr then stmt stmt’ | a
>
> stmt’ -> else stmt | EPSILON
>
> expr -> b

I tried to modify it and my result is:

> stmt -> if expr then stmt’’ | a
>
> stmt’’ -> stmt | stmt’
>
> stmt’ -> B else stmt
>
> expr -> b

But this does not generate the same language.

Can somebody help me modify the ambiguous grammar so that it is unambiguous and accepts the same language?

Comment: You've not defined B in the second grammar.

Answer (score 2):

Using the given grammar, there are two left most derivations for the string `if b then if b then a else a` as follows.

Derivation 1:

```
if expr then stmt stmt'
if b then stmt stmt'
if b then if expr then stmt stmt' stmt'
if b then if b then stmt stmt' stmt'
if b then if b then a stmt' stmt'
if b then if b then a stmt'
if b then if b then a else stmt
if b then if b then a else a
```

Derivation 2:

```
if expr then stmt stmt'
if b then stmt stmt'
if b then if expr then stmt stmt' stmt'
if b then if b then stmt stmt' stmt'
if b then if b then a stmt' stmt'
if b then if b then a else stmt stmt'
if b then if b then a else a stmt'
if b then if b then a else a
```

The parse trees remains same for most part. But after deriving `if b then if b then a stmt' stmt'`, the order of nodes changes thus affecting the structure of the tree. Hence the given grammar is ambiguous.

Comment: Though upvoted,but, OP asked for removing ambiguity of the grammar. I had a tough time even proving ambiguity. Thanks for brilliant effort.